# Can't get 'has_and_belongs_to_many' to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4

Made a previous post about this but after a lot of testing and changing it's outdated.

I'm trying to tie users and activities together.(One user can have several activities. An activity can have several users). I'ts pretty much a multi-user agenda thing.

Whenever i create a new activity i can select users by checkbox which will be doing the activity.

I can't get it to work though; The users won't show up in my activity show. Printing @activity.users in my show results in `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_User:0x43d2158>` but looping it, or checking my activities.js shows nothing(The activities.js shows "users":[] in the activity. So I'm pretty certain they're not associated properly.

Here's some code:

**The activities.js index method**

```
  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js {render_json @activities.to_json(:include => [:pictogram ,:users]) }
    end
  end
```

**The activities' form(Loops all users)**

```
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
  <% if @activity.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@activity.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this activity from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @activity.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :start_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :end_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="users">
    <% for user in User.all %>
      <label class="activity">
        <%= check_box_tag "activity[user_ids][]", user.id %>
        <%= user.name %>
      </label>
    <% end %>
  </div>


    <div class="pictograms">

      <% for p in Pictogram.all  %>
        <% #f.fields_for :pictograms do |x| %>
          <%= p %>
        <% #end %>
      <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**The schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130911095113) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "activities", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.integer  "pictogram_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "activities", ["pictogram_id"], name: "index_activities_on_pictogram_id", using: :btree

  create_table "activities_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "activity_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  add_index "activities_users", ["activity_id"], name: "index_activities_users_on_activity_id", using: :btree
  add_index "activities_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_activities_users_on_user_id", using: :btree

  create_table "pictograms", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "url"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "avatar"
    t.date     "birthdate"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

**Activity.rb**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pictogram
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictogram, allow_destroy: false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: false
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :activities

    validates_presence_of   :name, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of   :birthdate, :on => :create

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities, allow_destroy: false
end
```

And the **activity params from my activities controller**

```
def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:title, 
                                  :start_date, 
                                  :end_date, 
                                  :users,
                                  :pictogram)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sth like this:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pictogram
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictogram, allow_destroy: false

  def user_ids=(values)
    self.users << User.find(values)
  end
end

#controller

def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:title, 
                                  :start_date, 
                                  :end_date, 
                                  {:user_ids =>[]},
                                  :pictogram)
end
```

Comment: Aha, well spotted, he wasn't allowing the ids through.

Comment: Well spotted indeed @MichaeldeSilva. Nonetheless; It doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you also added user_ids= method?

Comment: Yes i did. In the activity.rb(And ditched the `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users`)

Comment: try `{ :user_ids => [] }` instead of `:user_ids` in `permit`

Comment: For pictogram it should be enough to allow pictogram_id in activity_params

Comment: @CaptainCarl See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try some minimalist debugging first,

```
User.create!(...)         # create a valid user record
Activity.create!(...)     # same as above
User.all.first.activities << Activity.all.first
User.all.first.activities.any?
```

See if this works, also keep an eye on your join_table and check that actual records are being persisted.  Your schema looks good as well.

Comment: @CaptainCarl did you try this yet?

Comment: Going to now! How do i join them though?

Comment: The `<<` operator does that for you :)  It's a method defined on associations.

Comment: `irb(main):008:0> User.all.first.activities.any?
  ←[1m←[36mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "us
ers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mActivity Exists (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "activities" INNER
JOIN "activities_users" ON "activities"."id" = "activities_users"."activity_id"
WHERE "activities_users"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
=> true`

Comment: There you go!  It's linking up fine.  `User.all.first.activities.first` will get you the first associated activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think, none of them read about the [strong_parameters with nested attributes](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) :

You can easily define `:users_attributes` in permit parameters for nested_attributes.

activities controller :

```
def activity_params
  params.require(:activity).permit(:title, 
                                  :start_date, 
                                  :end_date, 
                                  users_attributes: [:id])
end
```

This is the ideal way to do this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! I get an error though: `controllers/activities_controller.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' :users_attributes: [:id], ^ `

Also, does this mean i should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` again?

Comment: Ah, I've read the documentation and changed it. THe users is, again, empty though. So it didn't work.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do,  but the problem is that it won't assign a new user. When you pass an id to user_attributes, it is trying to update user with given id from given association, and will throw an error if it is not assigned.